# Unix encrypt file using public .asc key

Tags: unix, encryption, public-key-encryption

I have a file I need to encrypt with a public key I got `public.asc`. This key was shared with me over encrypted email. I have a zip file that I need to encrypt using this public key and share over SFTP.

I tried using openssl:

```
openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey public.asc -pubin -in file.zip -out file.zip.enc
```

but openssl displays the flag options and no error message. Also, I'm suspecting that .asc files should be encrypted with some other software.

Thanks

Comment: [This question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12260/41515) looks very relevant. Summary: encrypting files with RSA directly is not normal; rsautl only works on short inputs; you should use a symmetric cipher to encrypt your file, encrypt the symmetric key with RSA and send them together; gnupg is a better tool for the job then openssl

Comment: Can you look into the asc-file? Maybe it contains just a public pgp key.

Comment: @ott yes it is a public pgp key. I tried encrypting with gnupg too, but couldn't.

Comment: You can't encrypt it directly with that key, you have to import it into your keychain before (`gpg --import file.asc`). Then `gpg -se -r toName file`.